# What's the difference between $|\nabla f|$ and $\nabla f$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

what's the difference between $|\nabla f|$ and $\nabla f$ for example in :

$$\nabla\cdot{\nabla f\over|\nabla f|}$$

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question

Comment: You might want to have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del), for the different uses of the _del_ operator.

Comment: The vertical bars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$|\nabla f|$ is the magnitude of the $\nabla f$ vector. The expression $\frac{\nabla f}{|\nabla f|}$ is thus a unit vector.

$\nabla$ (gradient) acts on a scalar to give a vector, and $\nabla\cdot$ (divergence) acts on a vector to give a scalar.